# Can't set up profile with latest version of RSelenium for firefox

Tags: rselenium

this code ran for last version I used in July:

```
fprof <- getFirefoxProfile("c:/Users/cp/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/j7a5lq0r.selenium", useBase = T)
rS <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4567L, extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

but now the output is:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$`moz:profile

[1] "C:\\Users\\cp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.7n9y6eVCqnpt"
```

so it creates some temporary profile not loading the set one. Anyone knows what's the issue? This profile is valid and is ok while start FF manually.

Comment: See https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/143 . Firefox is currently through geckodriver half way between moving from the JSONwireprotocol spec to the w3c spec. Consider using an older version of firefox via docker or google chrome

Comment: So the recipe is to rebuild the profile in new firefox (even in the RSelenium client) and save it somewhere to load on startup