# Rselenium makeFirefoxProfile not implemented

Tags: r, windows, rselenium

I am trying to run a RSelenium instance to download some pdf files for me without having to click on the dialog boxes (or it opening using pdfjs).

But even if I set my configurations, the Firefox instance still loads the default profile.

RSelenium version: `1.73`

Firefox version: `56.0 (32-bit)`

Windows: `7 Ultimate`

Create profile and start server:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(stringi)

cprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  pdfjs.disabled = TRUE,
  plugin.scan.plid.all = FALSE,
  plugin.scan.Acrobat = "99.0",
  browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = 'application/pdf',
  browser.download.dir = "C:\\temp")
)

remDr <- rsDriver(port = 4477L, browser = "firefox", check = FALSE, extraCapabilities = cprof)

remDr <- remDr[["client"]]
```

After Firefox launches I check the configs, the settings have remained in their default state:
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101552/cant-set-up-profile-with-latest-version-of-rselenium-for-firefox